# Convert string to int in a list by removing floating (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, int, converters

I have a list like this:

```
List= [("Mike,"Admin","26,872"),
       ("John,"Admin","32,872"),
       ("Mark,"Admin","26,232")...]
```

what I want to achieve is the following:

```
List= [("Mike,"Admin", 26872),
       ("John,"Admin", 32872),
       ("Mark,"Admin", 26232)...]
```

so for the every third element I want to remove comma and convert it to int.
I tried for example to do replace but the list doesn't support replace method.

Just a test:

```
    accounts = sorted(List, key=lambda account: account[2], reverse=True)
    for i,j,k in accounts:
         k.replace(",", "")
         int k
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
[(a, b, c.replace(",", "")) for a, b, c in List]
```

This will create a new list having the first two values unchanged, and the third with the comma being removed.

If you want to have the third value as an `int`, you can simply.. cast it.

Note that you can iterate on the list in a different way,

```
[(w[0], w[1], w[2]) for w in List]
```

Comment: got beaten by a minute :P removing mine :)